# What is the proper replacement of the Resteasy 2.X ClientErrorInterceptor?

Tags: exception, jakarta-ee, resteasy

We are working on the migration from resteasy 2.x to 3.x and are not happy about the use of the deprecated `org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponse` within `org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.ClientErrorInterceptor#handle` - method.

Thus we are searching for proper replacement with which we are able to rethrow all service exception at a single place within the service client library, even if `ClientResponse` is replaced in new versions of resteasy.

The existing solution with resteasy 2.x looks like:

```
public class ServiceClientErrorInterceptor implements ClientErrorInterceptor
{
    @Override
    public void handle(ClientResponse<?> response)
    {
        throw response.getEntity(ServiceExceptionObject.class).getException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to migrate to a newer version of RESTEasy than 3.x? That stream will not be seeing any more releases. Are you open to the MicroProfile REST Client API?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, resteasy upgrade is part of the migration from eap6 to eap7, hence resteasy 3.x is required.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no Resteasy replacement available. So i decieded to use a standard Java-EE Interceptor for that purpose, which works fine.